# Get location of vertices for Collision Detection OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rotation, collision-detection, vertex

I am trying to figure out how to get the vertices of my cube after it has been rotates with `glRotate3f()`

Im using a sphere bounding box to narrow dow the possible collisions but I need to know the exact vertices to get an accurate collision. Can anyone help me figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for, but you're approaching your problem from the wrong angle. OpenGL should be used to draw your scene and only that. Scene management and anything that goes along with it (transformations, deformations...to name just a few) should be handled by you (or an appropriate framework).

Comment: What is your suggestion on the collision detection then? doing the vector rotations would be extremely consuming on the memory, especially for the larger objects with a hundred or more vertecies

Comment: I think you mean "computationally intensive" instead of "memory consuming"? If so, a hundred ore more vertices is not that big of a deal. And once you really get into trouble, you might want to have a look at bounding volume hierarchies to help you out. Christer Ericson's [Real-time Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net) is absolutely worth a read if you're interested. As is the blog.